# Retrieving text from radiobutton in a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, radio-button, viewflipper, radio-group

how should i get the text of selected radiobutton placed in a viewFlipper..??
I have a RadioGroup wherein i have placed all my radiobuttons !

Answer (score 1):

You need just get current view from ViewFlipper using viewflipper.getDisplayedChild(); and then radioButton.getText().